# How to unzip a split zip file in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, unzip

I have a **split zip file** (created by **winzip in window**) , then ftp to hadoop server.
Somehow i can't unzip it through something like below command

The files like below

```
file.z01,file.zo2,file.zo3....file.zip
```

Then i run below command

```
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/Links.txt.gz | gzip -d | hadoop fs -put - /tmp/unzipped/Links.txt
```

Then Error comes up

```
cat: Unable to write to output stream
```

What i expect is that unzip those split files to Hadoop particular folder

Answer (score 0):

Unclear how `Links.txt.gz` is related to your `.zip` part files...

Hadoop doesn't really understand ZIP format (especially split ones), and `gzip -d` wouldn't work on `.zip` files anyway.

[Zip nor gzip](http://comphadoop.weebly.com/) are splittable in Hadoop processing (read "able to be computed in parallel"), so since WinZip supports BZ2 format, I suggest you switch to that, and I don't see a need to create split files in Windows unless it's to upload the file faster...

Sidenote: `hadoop fs -cat /input | <anything> | hadoop fs -put - /output` is not splitting "in Hadoop"... You are copying the raw text of the file to your local buffer, then doing an operation locally, then optionally streaming it back to HDFS.